# Jira: Obtener tareas realizadas el día de hoy mediante JQL

Tags: jira, jql

trabajando con [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) por medio de [Jql](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-764478330.html),

> trato de obtener las tareas con estatus `done` y `approved` del día de
> hoy

.

Estoy definiendo un rango a partir de la fecha de hoy por medio de la función `Now()` y menos 1 día (-1d), al parecer no da resultado :

```
Updated < Now() AND Updated = -1d AND (status = done OR status = approved)
```

Al ejecutar el query obtengo las tareas del día de hoy, pero también se obtienen las del día anterior, deseo obtener únicamente las de día de hoy.

Comment: Probaste con esta condición? `Updated > startOfDay(-0d)` porque según tengo entendido `-1d` te devuelve hoy y ayer.

Comment: gracias Pablo, precisamente estaba probando startOfDay(), pero con -0d como parámetro me parece que no tiene relevancia, me parece que es similar a startOfDay(0) o me equivoco?.

Comment: Ah claro. No lo puedo probar porque no me carga los proyecto Jira. No sé que pasó. ¿Te sirvió para algo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probá con está condición:

```
Updated >= startOfDay(0) AND (status = done OR status = approved)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, investigando un poco use este query: updatedDate > startOfDay(0) AND updatedDate < endOfDay(0) AND (status = done OR status = approved) pero creo que únicamente Updated >= startOfDay(0) puede realizar el Query correctamente.

Comment: Buenidimo. Me queme varias neuronas armando consultas en las incidencias. Me encantaría poder usar sql estándar.

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo [este ejemplo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-functions-reference-764478342.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-startOfDaystartOfDay()) de la documentación, intenta con:

```
updated > startOfDay() AND status IN ("Done", "Approved")
```

Comment: Gracias Paul, pero obtengo datos de hoy y ayer, anteriormente traté un query similar...

Comment: ¡Ah! De acuerdo. Bastaría con `startOfDay()`.